# How can I add number at the end of pages in this document format latex?

Tags: page-numbering

I have a document of this type and I would like to add number pages at the end

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt, twoside]{article}
```

Comment: What do you mean by add pages at the end? empty pages?

Comment: @moewe Sorry I mean numbers at the end of pages

Comment: Page numbers should be displayed on most pages unless you explicitly turned them off. Please show us a complete example document that reproduces what you are currently seeing. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean adding a couple of empty pages at the end? If so, then you can put a couple of `\newpage` at the end like the following:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\newpage
\lipsum[1-3]
\newpage
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: sorry I mean adding number at the end of pages

Comment: Do you mean page numbers? They are displayed automatically unless you turn them off.